# AJAX POST JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have AJAX POST, the result is JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../../api/test",
  data: JSON.stringify(source),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (result) {
    var upload = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(upload);
  }
});
```

The upload result is:

```
{"Link":0,"Title":"d","Description":"dada","Keywords":"dad"}
```

How can I get the value of Title?

Comment: `result` is an object.  Just use it.

Comment: I highly recommend simply posting the POST rather than creating a JSON string which the server has to decode. What is the server technology you are using? PHP, ASP, Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not stringify the result, just use `result.Title`.

Comment: Yup. For future reference, if you ever have any doubts about what you are getting back, it is a good idea to debug the script inside your browser. Just set a breakpoint inside the `success` function and you can see the contents of `result` that you get back.

Answer (score -1):

As you already have JSON string, It's simple as a pie!
All you need to do is to call the property you want from the variable you assigned your result to.

for example:

```
var post_response;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../api/test",
    data: JSON.stringify(source),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        post_response = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log("Title: "+post_response.Title);
    }
 });
```

hope this helps.

Comment: `post_response` will be empty at the time you try to log it, because it gets populated inside the async callback.

Comment: jQuery knows that you use contentType json and converts json to object for you, you do not need JSON.parse (here your typo) for that

Comment: ^ moonwave99, my bad.. I just modified my code.

@kitty, I just copied the code the user wrote above ^